# Использование тегов aside и article

Tags: html, html5

Незнаю как вам а мне кажется разметка html5 немного путаной, так например в примерах указано что основное содержимое включая шапку можно помещать в тег article. Также сказано что этот тег приднозначен для разных новостей. В связи с этим возникает вопрос, можно ли использовать тег article в том же самом теги article.
Также хочется знать если страница помещена в article, то можно ли вставив тег aside, разместить туда article

```
<article>
    .....
    <aside>
       <article>
       </article>
    </aside>
    ..
</article>
<footer>

</footer>
```

будет ли такой код с точки зрения семантики правильным?

Answer (score 2):

[**Вот, почитайте**](http://www.xiper.net/learn/tegofenshuj/html5/structural-markup-with-html5-1.html). Думаю будет интересно и все встанет на свои места. 
Структурная разметка с HTML5 (3 части).

Answer (score 1):

Логически неправильно размещать в article aside, article по идее должны быть в контейнере. Располагать новости в aside не очень хорошая мысль. Скорее всего у вас там превью новостей как у меня, я для этого использую div'ы.